# Angular dynamic menu

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a mat menu below with each of them has each own click value and with own disable properties , is there a way we can cleanly implement this or dynamically implement this without repeating the buttons and click as you see on the current progress below? something like dynamic

#code

```
  <mat-menu #createDealMenu="matMenu" xPosition="before" yPosition="below">
      <button [disabled]="!testID" (click)="createDeal(DEAL_TYPES.AC)" mat-menu-item>Portfolio Management - Approval to Close</button>
      <button [disabled]="!pmRId" (click)="createDeal(DEAL_TYPES.PMT)" mat-menu-item>Portfolio Management - Termination Option</button>
      <button [disabled]="!leaseId" (click)="createDeal(DEAL_TYPES.PMR)" mat-menu-item>{{DEAL_TYPES.PMR}}</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Comment: Look directives like ngFor. Just create an object containing all the parameters and info u need and then loop it with the ngFor

Comment: Thank you Sir , appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component logic there must be an object containing all the parameters and info you will need in order to fill up the mat-menu.

Something like this:

```
public menuItems: any[]; // Would be nice to create an interface or something to deal with the types

.. code ...

// Inside the ngOnInit():

this.menuItems = [
  { disabledCondition: !this.testID, dealType: 'AC', buttonText: 'Portfolio Management - Approval to Close'
]
```

So now that we have an item in the array we will use the ngFor directive to loop over the array and show all the items as we want.

The HTML file:

```
<mat-menu #createDealMenu="matMenu" xPosition="before" yPosition="below">
    <button *ngFor="let item of menuItems" 
            [disabled]="item.disableCondition"
            (click)="createDeal(DEAL_TYPES[item.dealType])" mat-menu-item
    > 
      {{ item.buttonText }}

    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Something like this might suit for you

Comment: Thank you Sir , appreciated.